# passing properties in callback function nodejs

Tags: node.js, redirect, parameter-passing, paypal-sandbox

I'm using **paypal-rest-sdk**. Problem I'm facing is, when I'm making an authorizationUrl call, I want to pass some parameters which can be accessed in the redirected URL.

**Below is my code**

```
 import paypal from 'paypal-rest-sdk';
 const openIdConnect = paypal.openIdConnect;

  paypal.configure({
                mode: "sandbox" 
                client_id: //MyClientId,
                client_secret: //MySecretId,
                openid_redirect_uri: `http://myRedirectionEndpoint/account/domestic/paypal/callback?state={accountId:5e8c2291d69ed1407ec86221}`
               });

  openIdConnect.authorizeUrl({scope: 'openid profile'});
```

Adding query parameter **state** gives the error as **invalid redirectUri**

What is the best way to pass the data that needs to be used after redirection

Answer (score 0):

I think you are slightly misunderstanding how oauth authorization works. Basically if you want to get any data you need to do this AFTER you consume the callback and validate the user in your system as well.

Have you ever seen for Google/github etc openid auth provider returning some data that corresponds to the caller system's data? It's not possible.

You are probably confusing this with webhook where the caller system calls a webhook with some data internally and you capture it. Which is commonly used in payment transactions.

But the auth is slightly different. For auth there are 3 systems.

1. **the actual auth provider** (Paypal/google/github) etc.
2. **an Identity provider** which basically gets profile data etc and other than for enterprise systems these two systems are simply same.
3. the caller system which is your NodeJS service in this case.

**=>** Now caller-system calls the auth provider to get some kind of code generally an auth code. This means the user exists in auth system let's say Google.

**=>** Then the caller-system calls the identity provider with that auth code checking if the user is there in identity provider(idp) as well and the idp returns access_token, id_token, refresh_token etc (as I said most of the time these are same systems). But consider amazon, let's say you want to login to *Amazon* with your *Google* account. You have a *Google* account alright but you don't have amazon account. So you will get the auth code but will not get the id_token.

**=>** Now the id_token most of the time contains some basic info of the user in JWT format. But Now the ACCESS_TOKEN is used to do all the other calls to your system(caller system). Now as I said id_token some kind of user data. You can have a db table mapping userid with account number in your NodeJs service.

**=>** Make an endpoint to get the account number or something which takes access_token and id_token. First validate the access_token and verify the signature of the id_token then decrypt the token to get basic user info. and use that id to fetch the data from your table and use that data.

**After Edit:**

You can see in the [doc](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK):

```
paypal.configure({
  'openid_client_id': 'CLIENT_ID',
  'openid_client_secret': 'CLIENT_SECRET',
  'openid_redirect_uri': 'http://example.com' });

// Authorize url
paypal.openIdConnect.authorizeUrl({'scope': 'openid profile'});

// Get tokeninfo with Authorize code
paypal.openIdConnect.tokeninfo.create("Replace with authorize code", function(error, tokeninfo){
  console.log(tokeninfo);
});

// Get userinfo with Access code
paypal.openIdConnect.userinfo.get("Replace with access_code", function(error, userinfo){
  console.log(userinfo);
});
```

When you get the auth code, you use it to call the `paypal.openIdConnect.tokeninfo.create` and get the tokens. Then use those tokens to call the `paypal.openIdConnect.userinfo.get` to get the user Info. Now when you get the userinfo you will be able to create the db row that you wanted to create.

You can add those two below calls in your `/callback` route.

Comment: yes i understand that flow somewhat. I will update the question more to explain the scenario.

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: userinfo from paypal i will get, how about the accountId which is expected from client

Comment: But for the accountId what are going to send to the client? and what is `client` here?

Comment: Client is a UI angular app, i dont have any mechanism on the service which holds the record of the current logged in user.